# Download netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to switch from eclipse to netbeans  The first thing I am trying do is download the correct version of netbeans.  However, when I follow the instrunctions to import a maven project it asks me to choose that from the left hand panel  (After a clicking on a new project)

But the only things listed are HTML5 and Javascript projects.

Are there special plugins or am I downloading the wrong version of netbeans?  I got here:  https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html  and download the java2EE version,  but I have not luck.   Any ideas?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

Since NetBeans is currently in the process of being handed over to Apache by Oracle there are actually four places where you can download different flavors of NetBeans at the moment:

1. The Oracle location you used is for NetBeans 8.2, the latest stable release. It supports the use of Java 8, but not Java 9 or Java 10.
2. There is also another Oracle location accessible from the link in your OP if you click the [Development link](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) in the top right corner of the page. That version, sometimes known as the "nightly build", also supports Java 9, but not Java 10, and includes some bug fixes not in 8.2
3. A third option is to download the initial beta Release of NetBeans 9 which supports all Java releases including Java 10, as well as EE 8 [from here](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans-java/incubating-9.0-beta/incubating-netbeans-java-9.0-beta-source.zip). See [the NetBeans 9 web site](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb90/nb90-beta.html) for more details. Maven version 3.3.9 is bundled with NetBeans, but you can also use your own external version if you prefer.
4. The fourth option, and the one I recommend if you are just getting started on NetBeans, is to use the latest release of NetBeans 9 with bug fixes. You can download the latest zip file (which runs on Linux/MacOS/Windows) [from here](https://builds.apache.org/job/incubator-netbeans-linux/).

The formal release of Netbeans 9 will be sometime next month.

Something is clearly wrong with your current setup if you do not see any options for creating a Java project in the New Project window. Is it possible that you downloaded the HTML5/JavaScript version of NetBeans rather than the Java EE version? They are right next to each other on the download page.

If that is the problem it is possible to upgrade by installing plugins, but it would be much simpler to download again using any of the options described above. You can safely run multiple versions of NetBeans concurrently if you want to try them out, though the GUI is pretty much the same in all cases.

If you only need Java 8/EE 7 then you can stick with option #1, but I you want to use Java 9 and/or Java10 and/or EE 8 then use option #4.

Comment: Thanks,  I was having trouble with installing maven throguh Netbeans,  and it was using the JRE,  which makes NO SENSE as it's an IDE.   Im working through it.  I will investigate your options more thoroughly this weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Download the "All" version, then install maven separately.
Open netbeans and navigate to Tools > Options > Java > Maven and change the 'Maven Home' path to the directory where maven is installed.

Comment: I don't see a maven.  Only an ant tab.